# I wanted to add "headers" in the sendgrid request for setting the "Message-ID" parameter. I am using CURL request in PHP

Tags: php, sendgrid

I have constructed the body like this:

```
$params = [
  "personalizations" => [
    [
      "to" => [
        ["email" => "test@test.com"]
      ],
      "subject" => "testing subject for mail"
    ]
  ],
  "from" => [
    "email" => "check@check.com",
    "name" => $from_name
  ],
  "content" => [
    [
      "type" => "text/html",
      "value" => $message
    ]
  ],
  "headers" => [
    "Message-ID" => "<253618-testing-header>"
  ]
];
```

and sending like this:

```
$request =  $url . 'api/mail.send.json';
$cr = curl_init($request);
curl_setopt($cr, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($params));
curl_setopt($cr, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($cr, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Authorization: Bearer test"));
curl_setopt($cr, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$response = curl_exec($cr);
$out = json_decode($response, true);
```

But it shows empty from email address (required).

Normally we are using the params like this:

```
$params = array(
'to'        => $to,
'subject'   => $subject,
'html'      => $message,
'from'      => $from,
'fromname'  => $from_name,
);
```

but now i wanted to set the Message-ID header so someone suggested the before mentioned way.

Could someone Please help?

Answer (score 1):

It appears you're using version 2 of the SendGrid API, but the new example code and data structure you've tried to use is for version 3.

Instead you should look at the V2 documentation and see how headers should be added to messages in that version.

Setting your headers parameter like this:

```
$params = array(
'to'        => $to,
'subject'   => $subject,
'html'      => $message,
'from'      => $from,
'fromname'  => $from_name,
'headers'   => [
    "Message-ID" => "<253618-testing-header>"
  ]
);
```

should solve your problem.

Always verify that examples you are given are relevant, and double-check them against the correct documentation for the version of the API you're using. Don't just blindly copy them and hope for the best - that will often lead to the kind of frustration which prompted you to ask this question.

Reference:

- v2 documentation: https://docs.sendgrid.com/v2-api/mail
- v3 documentation: https://docs.sendgrid.com/api-reference/mail-send/mail-send#body

Comment: Hi, thanks for the help. I tried to send the header like this but for some reason it gives an error empty from email (required). though when i printed the object it did contain all the parameters. Issue comes when I use <> in message id body.